# Reference variable and virtual functions

Tags: c++, reference, pure-virtual

I've found a strange behavior while using a reference variable.

Here is class implementations:

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual void Method() = 0;
};

class DerivedA : public Base {
    public:
        virtual void Method() {}
}

class DerivedB : public Base {
    public:
        virtual void Method() {}
}
```

Here is an example code which have the strange behavior:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    DerivedA a;
    DerivedB b;
    Base &base = a;

    base.Method();   // Calls DerivedA::Method

    base = b;
    base.Method();   // Calls DerivedA::Method!!! Why doesn't call DerivedB.Method()?
}
```

In conclusion, it seems that the virtual function pointer table "associated" to the reference variable is determine only when initializing the reference variable. If I re-assign the reference variable the *vfpt* doesn't change.

What happens here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Base &base` is a reference, i.e. alias to the `a` object, so the assignment `base = b` is equivalent to `a = b`, which leaves the `base` thingie still the same object of the same class. It is not a reassignment of pointer as you seem to assume.

Comment: I think this answer deserves the green tick!

Comment: Thanks, though accepted answer is the one questioner has accepted and it's okay that he accepted the other answer ;-)

Answer (score 7):

References can only be initialized once. You can not assign a new object to a reference. What is actually happening here is that operator= of Base is called and the underlying object is still DerivedA and not DerivedB.

Comment: I am not sure this is correct actually. The operator= is not defined in Base, so there is nothing to call really, apart from C++ default implementation of operator=. I think what is happening here is what @MichaelKrelin answered below.

Comment: @Rafid As you wrote, there's the default implementation of operator=. The default implementation is not virtual and the type of base is Base so Base::operator=() is called. Michael answer is correct too. The two answers do not contradict each other.

Comment: This answer contradicts neither my answer nor the truth. The only thing that bothers me is how is it important that the default `operator=` implementation is not virtual? ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Just noting that which operator is to be called is dependent only on the type of the reference and not dependent on the type of the object.

Comment: Yeah, though was it to depend on the type of the reference it still would be `a`'s `operator=` ;-)